# OpenGL - Import 3ds object and make it solid?

Tags: object, opengl, 3ds

Basically, what I'm trying to do is, import the 3ds object(done) and make it look "solid" so that I can apply lightning to it

This is part of what I got:

this is where I load the object and put it on screen

```
void render()
{
int l_index;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |  GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Modeling transformation
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-500.0);
glColor3d(1,1,0);


glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); 
for (l_index=0;l_index<object.polygons_qty;l_index++)
{

    glVertex3f( object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].a ].x,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].a ].y,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].a ].z);


    glVertex3f( object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].b ].x,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].b ].y,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].b ].z);


    glVertex3f( object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].c ].x,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].c ].y,
                object.vertex[ object.polygon[l_index].c ].z);
}
glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

initializer

```
void init(){
angle=30;
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

 // Projection transformation
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
glLoadIdentity(); 

glOrtho(-100.0f,100.0f,-100.0f,100.0f,100.0f,-100.0f);
gluPerspective(30.0f,(GLfloat)screen_width/(GLfloat)screen_height,10.0f,10000.0f);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // We enable the depth test (also called z buffer)
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); 

CThreeMaxLoader::Load3DS(&object,"chesspawn.3ds");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that `glPolygonMode()` call if you want solid fills.

For lighting make sure to supply some appropriate vertex/face normals.